How to send an image to Django using Flutter web?
I'm working on a project that uses Flutter web as the client and Django as the backend server. I'm currently working on a registration form that requires to send an image + additional data.
My problem is that it seems that there is an issue concerning the file upload, my view is working correctly in Django (I tested it many times) and wen i remove the file field from the django server, the request works perfectly, so I geuss the problem is in the file upload.
final reader = html.FileReader();
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(logo);
      await reader.onLoad.first;
      final imageData = reader.result as List<int>;
      final request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
      final multipartFile =
          http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('logo', imageData, filename: 'Any_name');
      request.files.add(multipartFile);
      request.fields["nom"] = nom;
      request.fields["secteur_activite"] = secteurActivite;
      request.fields["description"] = description;
      request.fields["email"] = email;
      request.fields["first_name"] = firstname;
      request.fields["last_name"] = lastname;
      request.fields["phone"] = phone;
      request.fields["password"] = password;
      request.fields["password2"] = password2;

      final response = await request.send();

I've worked before with file uplaod between Django and Flutter and I always had problem using the .fromBytes method, the .fromPath method works fine but this method isn't available for Flutter web.
Here is my Django code:
class EntrepriseRegistrationView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = EntrepriseSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request):
        request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            data = serializer.data
            print(data)
            print(data.get("access_token"))
            return Response({
                "data": data,
                'message': "Votre inscription s'est effectué avec succès",
            },status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

